# Keeping a Button under WebView in Android

Tags: android, layout, webview

I have trouble displaying(and most importantly - keeping) a Button under WebView, so it will stay there and not get eaten up by WebView after a call of loadUrl(). I can see the Button in the right place when the emulator starts up, but when  the page loads, the WebView always occupies the whole screen. Android SDK is 1.5.

Here is the layout:

```
<RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout01" 
                android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

  <Button android:text="Ok" 
          android:id="@+id/btnOk" 
          android:layout_width="120px" 
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
          android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
          android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>
    <WebView android:id="@+id/webview1"
           android:layout_above="@+id/btnOk"
           android:layout_width="fill_parent"
           android:layout_height="fill_parent"
           /> 
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set `android:layout_weight="1"` on your WebView element and enclose it in a LinearLayout:

```
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/LinearLayout01" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

  <WebView android:id="@+id/webview1"
         android:layout_above="@+id/btnOk"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="fill_parent"
         android:layout_weight="1"/> 
  <Button android:text="Ok" 
          android:id="@+id/btnOk" 
          android:layout_width="120px" 
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
          android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Only thing I changed in my above layout is adding layout-weight="1" and keeping everything else, but it works. Or should I still change to LinearLayout?

Comment: No. If it works as-is then feel free to stick with it. I'm please that it fixed things for you.